# GrafOverflow - Metric collection for Stack Exchange

Tags: app, statistics, node.js

## GrafOverflow

A metric collection script for the Stack Exchange API.

### View Some Realtime Stats

Here is a link for you to view some stats in real* time, with one year of history!

[**GrafOverflow**](https://manage.mclarkdev.com/grafana/dashboard/db/stack-stats)

[image: Screenshot of Dasboard]

*Stats are collected every 5 minutes and are smoothed to a 30 minute average (on a query) to account for API caching.

### About

Data is beautiful, so why not draw some beautiful graphs about the sites that helps so many?

This script is based around the [carbon-cache](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html) metric storage backend and is using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) for the UI.

To query the API, I wrote up a **Node.js** script that will run a collection on a 5 minute interval; this then parses the JSON response from the Stack Exchange API into a format parsable by the metric engine, opens a socket, and sends it.

In the above screenshot, you can see the result of simply collecting and graphing the data returned by the [/info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info) API endpoint.

The list of statistics collected and graphed:

- Total Votes
- Total Questions
- Total Answers
- Total Comments
- Total Accepted
- Accepted Percentage
- Total Users
- Total Badges

All *per minute* stats shown in Grafana are calculated by applying time function transformations to the *total* counts.

#### Multi Site Support

The configuration accepts a list of sites to poll. The hosted instance has the following sites available:

- stackoverflow.com
- serverfault.com
- superuser.com
- gaming.stackexchange.com
- askubuntu.com
- math.stackexchange.com
- apple.stackexchange.com
- 3dprinting.stackexchange.com

#### Download

The script source can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/mclarkdev/GrafOverflow).

Following in the path of Stack Exchange, this is published under the [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).

#### Requirements

The application is built in **Node.js** and outputs data in the [carbon plaintext protocol](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/feeding-carbon.html#the-plaintext-protocol).

This applications requires an instance of carbon-cache or equivalent metric storage engine to properly store stats; in addition, it requires a front end viewer - in this example, I am using graphite-web and Grafana.

#### Configuration & Usage

To configure the application, simply copy `config.sample.js` to `config.js` and adjust your desired parameters.

To start the application, simply run the main file with node.

```
cd $APP_HOME
node stackstats.js &>> log &
```

### Contact

Created by:
  Matthew Clark
  matt@mclarkdev.com

***Update 9/13/18***Sorry, the domain name expired for some time there, but I never stopped collecting metrics! I have updated the active link, metrics can again be viewed with **one year of history**.

Comment: Any chance you could allow us to change the amount of time something is counted on a certain gauge, for instance I'd like to view some of the slower sites with 'x per hour' instead of 'x per minute' gauges.

Comment: [Is this what you want](https://manage.mclarkdev.com/grafana/dashboard/db/stack-stats-raw)? I am not too happy with it, but I don't have a ton of flexibility in allowing dashboard modifications :/ In the top left, there is a new field, *Scale* in seconds. Change this from 60 to 3600 to view rates as, X per Hour, change it to 86,400 to view rates a X per day.

Comment: Yeah, I see why you're not too happy with that, but it does what I requested. Thanks. It really is more useful to be able to see [ubuntu.se]'s stats as 5.33 Q/hr & 3.33 A/hr than .09 Q/min & .06 A/min.

Comment: You don't want to follow [the naming convention for Stack Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section) for your application? That would be *Graf Overflow*.